# websocket client packet unframe/unmask

Tags: erlang, websocket

I am trying to implement latest websocket spec. However, i am unable to get through the unmasking step post successful handshake.

I receive following web socket frame:

```
<<129,254,1,120,37,93,40,60,25,63,71,88,92,125,80,81,73,
51,91,1,2,53,92,72,85,103,7,19,79,60,74,94,64,47,6,83,
87,58,7,76,87,50,92,83,70,50,68,19,77,41,92,76,71,52,
70,88,2,125,90,85,65,96,15,14,20,107,31,14,28,100,27,9,
17,122,8,72,74,96,15,86,68,37,68,18,76,48,15,28,93,48,
68,6,73,60,70,91,24,122,77,82,2,125,80,81,85,45,18,74,
64,47,91,85,74,51,21,27,20,115,24,27,5,37,69,80,75,46,
18,68,72,45,88,1,2,40,90,82,31,37,69,76,85,103,80,94,
74,46,64,27,5,60,75,87,24,122,25,27,5,47,71,73,81,56,
21,27,93,48,88,76,31,57,77,74,11,55,73,68,73,115,65,81,
31,104,26,14,23,122,8,75,68,52,92,1,2,110,24,27,5,53,
71,80,65,96,15,13,2,125,75,83,75,41,77,82,81,96,15,72,
64,37,92,19,93,48,68,7,5,62,64,93,87,46,77,72,24,40,92,
90,8,101,15,28,83,56,90,1,2,108,6,13,21,122,8,82,64,42,
67,89,92,96,15,93,19,56,28,8,65,101,31,94,16,105,28,10,
20,56,30,14,65,56,27,93,71,106,16,11,17,63,25,4,17,57,
73,89,17,59,29,88,29,106,24,27,5,46,65,72,64,54,77,69,
24,122,66,93,93,49,5,12,8,109,15,28,76,59,90,93,72,56,
76,1,2,41,90,73,64,122,8,89,85,50,75,84,24,122,25,15,
23,105,25,5,19,106,26,14,20,111,25,27,5,53,77,85,66,53,
92,1,2,110,26,13,2,125,95,85,65,41,64,1,2,108,27,10,19,
122,7,2>>
```

As per base framing protocol defined here (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5.2) i have:

```
fin:1, rsv:0, opcode:1, mask:1, length:126
```

Masked application+payload data comes out to be:

```
<<87,58,7,76,87,50,92,83,70,50,68,19,77,41,92,76,71,52,70,88,2,125,90,85,65,96,
15,14,20,107,31,14,28,100,27,9,17,122,8,72,74,96,15,86,68,37,68,18,76,48,15,
28,93,48,68,6,73,60,70,91,24,122,77,82,2,125,80,81,85,45,18,74,64,47,91,85,
74,51,21,27,20,115,24,27,5,37,69,80,75,46,18,68,72,45,88,1,2,40,90,82,31,37,
69,76,85,103,80,94,74,46,64,27,5,60,75,87,24,122,25,27,5,47,71,73,81,56,21,
27,93,48,88,76,31,57,77,74,11,55,73,68,73,115,65,81,31,104,26,14,23,122,8,75,
68,52,92,1,2,110,24,27,5,53,71,80,65,96,15,13,2,125,75,83,75,41,77,82,81,96,
15,72,64,37,92,19,93,48,68,7,5,62,64,93,87,46,77,72,24,40,92,90,8,101,15,28,
83,56,90,1,2,108,6,13,21,122,8,82,64,42,67,89,92,96,15,93,19,56,28,8,65,101,
31,94,16,105,28,10,20,56,30,14,65,56,27,93,71,106,16,11,17,63,25,4,17,57,73,
89,17,59,29,88,29,106,24,27,5,46,65,72,64,54,77,69,24,122,66,93,93,49,5,12,8,
109,15,28,76,59,90,93,72,56,76,1,2,41,90,73,64,122,8,89,85,50,75,84,24,122,
25,15,23,105,25,5,19,106,26,14,20,111,25,27,5,53,77,85,66,53,92,1,2,110,26,
13,2,125,95,85,65,41,64,1,2,108,27,10,19,122,7,2>>
```

While the 32-bit masking key is:

```
<<37,93,40,60,25,63,71,88,92,125,80,81,73,51,91,1,2,53,92,72,85,103,7,19,79,60,
74,94,64,47,6,83>>
```

As per https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5.2 :

```
j                   = i MOD 4
transformed-octet-i = original-octet-i XOR masking-key-octet-j
```

however, i doesn't seem to get my original octet sent from client side, which is basically a xml packet. Any direction, correction, suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: indeed, however i don't see any change to base framing protocol. It is same as defined in the link above.

Comment: Check out misultin project on github. It has all websocket parsing codes you need. Original code uses process-based approach and it's a bit hard to reuse that code ( https://github.com/ostinelli/misultin/blob/master/src/misultin_websocket.erl ). If you need a functional foldl-like parsing code instead of process-based, take a look at my fork of misultin ( https://github.com/gleber/misultin/branches/functionalize-ws-code ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've mis-read the data framing section of the protocol spec.

Your interpretation of the first byte (129) is correct - fin + opcode 1 - final (and first) fragment of a text message.

The next byte (254) implies that the body of the message is masked and that the following 2 bytes provide its length (lengths of 126 or 127 imply longer messages whose length's can't be represented in 7 bits.  126 means that the following 2 bytes hold the length; 127 mean that its the following 4 bytes).

The following 2 bytes - 1, 120 - imply a message length of 376 bytes.

The following 4 bytes - 37,93,40,60 - are your mask.

The remaining data is your message which should be transformed as you write, giving the message

&ltbody xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' rid='2167299354' to='jaxl.im' xml:lang='en' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh' ack='1' route='xmpp:dev.jaxl.im:5222' wait='30' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' ver='1.1
0' newkey='a6e44d87b54461e62de3ab7874b184dae4f5d870' sitekey='jaxl-0-0' iframed='true' epoch='1324196722121' height='321' width='1366'/>

Comment: didn't yet tried it but i believe this is the catch. probably i did understood it right, but didn't implement it right (mostly due to improper handling of bit/binary inside my erlang code). Thanks for the right pointer, and yes indeed this is the packet i m looking for after unmasking :) will chalk out the rest from here, thanks